# Why does the mass of an object attached to a pendulum affect the damping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, drag, oscillators

I tested this out on a simulation (Algodoo) and found that a pendulum with a more massive object attached to it has a lower damping on its velocity. Why does this happen?

Comment: Friction at the string end and other energy loss factors might be more or less constant. Increasing the mass increases the gravitational pull, and the friction is now smaller in comparison. That could be an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The damping force is generally taken to be [Stokes drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law), so it is proportional to the velocity and the radius of the pendulum bob, but it is unaffected by the mass of the bob:

$$ F_\text{drag} \propto vR $$

the deceleration of the bob due to the drag is then simply $F/m$:

$$ a_\text{drag} \propto \frac{vR}{m} $$

and you can see immediately why the damping is inversely proportional to the mass of the bob.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume the drag force is the same (as long as the shape of the object is the same that will be true) regardless of the mass, then the change in momentum will be the same. But when an object is more massive, the same change in momentum results in a smaller change in velocity.

However, even if the massive object is larger, there is an argument why it will be less damped. This is because the damping is proportional to the projected area of the object, while the mass is proportional to the volume.

Assuming the object is a sphere of radius $r$, the area scales with $r^2$ and the mass scales with $r^3$. For quadratic drag, we consider

$$F = \frac12 \rho A v^2 C_D$$

Where $\rho$ is the density, $A$ the projected area ($\pi r^2$), $v$ the velocity and $C_D$ the drag coefficient - which we usually approximate to 0.5 for a sphere (although that depends on the Reynolds number ... but that dependence is usually neglected except for very small or very fast objects). If we make the object 2x larger, the friction force increases 4x, but the mass increases 8x - so still the acceleration will be smaller, and the damping will be less.